# How to run or debug flutter project on both android and iOS at ones?

Tags: debugging, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am building the application for both android and iOS. So, I am trying to run flutter project in android and iOS device simultaneously. So, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At flutter Interact they announced this option, the setup guide could be found on their [github wiki pages](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code):

Answer (score 0):

You can connect both devices to your computer and run `flutter run -d all` from the console.